# Reason: image not found

Tags: reactive-cocoa

When I try to use Carthage to add ReactiveCocoa lib to my new project,I got this exception .I work in Xcode7

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Result.framework/Result
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/74AD1FE2-7095-47D2-B059-520863050EE2/ReactiveCocoaTest.app/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework/ReactiveCocoa
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Hi @andyhuang have you solved this issue? cause I just met exactly the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is xcode is not load `ReactiveCocoa.framework`, so you must manually add `ReactiveCocoa.framework`. Check below image.

[image]

Comment: I am using `ReactiveObjc`, but have this issue, use your method do not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, my solution is:

In the `TARGET` -> `Build Setting` -> `Other Linker Flag` -> `delete the ReactiveCocoa framework`.

There is `ReactiveCocoa` in the `Other Linker Flag`, I have delete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when I use: $ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

I had the same problem and it's fixed now. You need to reinstall the gem which rebuilds the native executables. 
For homebrew:  $ gem install charlock_holmes 
should just work.

Try: uninstall the gem, uninstall icu4c, reinstall icu4c, reinstall the gem.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: when update   cocoapods and  rvm,  error reason:" image not found". 
then I use this  solve it

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the question!. I wanna import rac by the method of git document.

[image]

then got the same reason.and I've tried again. Found I don't follow 5 step.
just you need "Add ReactiveObjC.framework. RAC must also be added to any "Copy Frameworks" build phase. If you don't already have one, simply add a "Copy Files" build phase and target the "Frameworks" destination."

[image]

then it work out!